# Why is the IP address different between mobile devices and desktop/laptop?

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, ip-address, maxmind

I'm having 2 different IP address connecting on the same WiFi connection.

- Laptop/Desktop: 58.110.xxx.xxx
- iPad/Android phone: 66.249.xx.xxx

This difference causes my country detection rendered incorrectly between laptop and mobile devices. I use Geo php (maxmind) that's based on IP address.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If they were on the same network, wifi or otherwise, that scenario should be impossible.  Perhaps your mobile device is connecting via cellular data service?  On your laptop, check the network settings for gateway, netmask, etc. for some clues.

Comment: Disable your 2G/3G/4G in the iPad/Android and see. You should always get the same IP address if using a same network.

Comment: Jerry/Michael - They are disabled. My ipad is not SIM-enabled. I have also tried multiple locations and each location gives 2 different IP readings. Strange huh?

Comment: Another reason could be your iPad/Android has been configured to use a VPN tunnel. Can you visit http://www.ipaddress.my from all devices and let us know the ISP name?

Comment: Per ipaddress.my:

Laptop: 110.33.xxx.xxx (ISP: Optus Internet - Retail)
Android phone: 66.249.xx.xx (ISP: Google Inc)
ipad: 66.249.xx.xx (ISP: Google Inc)

All connected on the same wifi network. Is that because of the browser? If so, what php script etc possible to capture the right IP. As i need to identify the geo Country of our visitors.

Answer (score 5):

I might have figured out the issue. You are using Chrome in iPad and Android phone with "reduce data usage" feature enabled.

In this case, all your traffics are tunneling through Google servers to reduce data size. Therefore, all other web servers are detecting you as from USA (Google servers) instead of direct connection from Australia.

If you disable the "reduce data usage", you should get a direct connection from Australia to anywhere instead.

Please use http://ipaddress.my to test your IP address and ISP for confirmation.

Comment: Spont on! You are absolutely right on that Michael. But... having diagnosed the problem, is there any script to bypass this. The geo-country info is important as it will determine the content display for where the visitor is from.

Comment: You can disable this feature in Chrome.

(Android) Settings -> Advanced -> Data Server -> Off
(iOS) Setttings -> Advanced -> Bandwidth -> Data Server -> Off

Comment: Not from user's point of view. I'm saying if i'm a site owner and if my visitor has that "data saver" turned on. How do we workaround to bypass that. Otherwise, maxmind cant detect the correct country profile and thus incorrect content display to user

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't know the actual user IP address if user is behind a proxy like in Chrome.